# How to animate light's energy

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, light

I'm new to animation with blender, I can animate the rotation, position and scale of a light, but not the energy that it emits. Can anyone tell me how to animate the Energy value?

Comment: @cegaton You say I publish me response, no problem, but it is different to other places Exchange I think. also when you want to post an answer to your question Exchage, warns you if you want to do

Comment: Its's OK to answer your own question. The way questions are marked as solved is by accepting an answer.

Comment: @cegaton Thanks to improve the response, so it will be better and easier visual for other

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution.

For Blender Internal

In the Energy label: press right mouse button and select Insert Keyframe.

[image]

For Cycles:

Create an emission node and animate the strength.

[image]

Comment: This works with any setting that can be animated. You can also hover the mouse over it and press I on the keyboard.